# why crystal report is getting all records even with RecordSelectionFormula set?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using the following code for loading crystal reports.

```
 ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtablelogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

        Tables CrTables;

        crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "localhost";
        crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "dbclients";
        crconnectioninfo.UserID = "ssssssss";
        crconnectioninfo.Password = "xxxxxxx";  


      cryrpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\rpts\\" + dealerInfo.ResourceName);

            CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtablelogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crconnectioninfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo);
            }


            cryrpt.RecordSelectionFormula = getCustInfoRptSelection();
            cryrpt.Refresh();

            allReportViewer.ReportSource = cryrpt;
```

getCustInfoRptSelection() is getting a specific client 
but the report shows all the clients at first time and when i close the report and open it again it shows the correct record.
so basicly i have to open the report twice to get the correct data though the getCustInfoRptSelection() results is not changing.

and in this case the RecordSelectionFormula ="  {dealer.dealer_type_id}=2 and {dealer.DEALER_NAME} like '*Mark stall X*'"

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, and I found [this answer](http://scn.sap.com/message/8179989#8179989) on a SAP website that worked

1. Expand `Form1.vb|cs` to show `Form1.Designer.vb|cs` and double-click it to show its code
2. Find where the initial `crystalReportViewer1` properties are set in the the `InitializeComponent` method
3. Comment out or delete the following two lines:

   ```
   this.crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = ""
   this.crystalReportViewer1.ViewTimeSelectionFormula = ""
   ```

Apparently this was something that was added in one of their newer service packs, as this problem didn't start happening until after I upgraded the Crystal Reports framework for .Net

Comment: sadly i got error with field name is not known with your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This one nailed it.
Locate your Windows Form that contains the CrystalReportViewer Control.

Normally, your Windows Form has Resx file and designer file

Example:
[image]

Open the Designer file:

Delete the 2 lines below:

[image]

This I think is a bug.
I am using VS2015 VB.NET.

It worked!